# rename y axis text label in varImpPlot

Tags: r, plot, label, random-forest

Is it possible to rename the y axis text label in `varImpPlot` of `library(randomForest)`?

Here an example:

```
library (MASS)
library(randomForest)
set.seed (1)
train1 = sample (1: nrow(Boston ), nrow(Boston )/2)
rf.boston =randomForest(medv~.,data=Boston ,subset =train1 ,mtry=6, importance =TRUE)
varImpPlot (rf.boston,n.var=4 )
```

Comment: you are welcome to click the check mark to resolve this question

Answer (score 1):

You could always check the function arguments. Ellipses (`...`, these things) indicate passing of arguments from one function to another. In this case, you could check that the variable labels are options you can set to the `dotchart` function.

```
varImpPlot(rf.boston,n.var=nvar, sort = F,
            labels = rep("random variable name",5))
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand.
If I use your posted command I have "random variable name" plotted for 5 times. How should i change it to have different labels ?

Comment: I had no idea what labels you wanted to have had plotted there. So I didn't assign any. The function works by sorting the mean squared prediction error of the random forest into highest or lowest, depending on whether `sort` is true or false. Afterwards it assigns the variable names for those `n.var` numbered variables to the dotplot's y-axis. I don't see a reason why you would change this other than to elucidate the variable names with something longer. i.e., you might want to change nox to 'nitrous oxide concentration'